# Cannot resolve firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I got this code from udacity while doing firebase course but there is an error in the import statement.

```
 import com.firebase.client.Firebase;

 public class ShoppingListApplication extends android.app.Application {                   

 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    }
```

It shows Cannot resolve firebase.

Comment: The Udacity course uses a old version of firebase. I suggest you head over to https://firebase.google.com/ and follow those instructions to install firebase.

Comment: ok thanks bro, but I need to know that what is the problem here means why there is an error in the IMPORT statement

Comment: Did you add the necessary gradle dependencies?

Answer (score 7):

You have not added

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
```

in your dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

After adding it.. just sync project once.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you go through https://firebase.google.com/ and follow the get started guide. They will tell you what gradle dependencies you need to add. Your import isn't resolving because you are missing a compile statement in your gradle build.

Answer (score 0):

Add com.firebase:firebase-client to your dependencies in your app gradle:

```
dependencies {

    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
```